# How can I create nested dashboards in grafana

Tags: java, breadcrumbs, grafana

Currently I have set of dashboards but I want to create a parent child relation among them so that I can create breadcrumbs. I am totally new to Grafana. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why it's related to java?